# What does -> _ => mean in Scala/Lift?

Tags: scala, lift

In "Simply Lift" REST examples we can find

```
case Nil JsonGet _ => Item.inventoryItems: JValue
```

but

```
case Nil JsonPut Item(item) -> _ => Item.add(item): JValue
```

Why `-> _ =>` instead of `_ =>`? And what's that `Nil` for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a topic on the mailing list recently: [Help understanding RestHelper serve params](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/ooNHGP3cH0U/pw8NXBxMyqYJ).

Basically, it is a series on `unapply` methods written in infix style. This means it is equivalent to writing it

```
case JsonGet(Nil, _) => Item.inventoryItems: JValue
```

and

```
case JsonPut(Nil, Item(item) -> _) => Item.add(item): JValue // or
case JsonPut(Nil, Tuple2(Item(item), _)) => Item.add(item): JValue
// using that -> denotes a Tuple
```

which makes it appear a bit less voodoo.